# Creating Title String in sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity-4

I am trying to create a unique title in *sitefinity*, the current title is something like this: "Chicken Sandwich". This is the code that is creating the title:

```
Page.Title  = (this._Product.PageTitle != "" ) ? this._Product.PageTitle : this._Product.Name;
```

I want to title to be something like this "Nutritional Information for Chicken Sandwich".

Comment: I'm a little unclear what the question is. is this code you've posted running in a control, and you want to change the title of the page it is on? what is the Product, a custom module item? or something from the ecommerce module?

Comment: The code is running in a Master Template Files. The product is a sandwich, and to my knowledge it is not running the ecommerce module.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitefinity 4/5 you kind of have 2 different titles. The first one is the 'name' of the page, the second is the Title for search engines. The name is seen throughout the backend of Sitefinity and is used in the navigation widgets. See screenshot [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19007909/sitefinity-pages.PNG)

You can retrieve both by the following statements:

```
string shorttitle = new PageManager().GetPageNode(new Guid(SiteMapBase.GetCurrentProvider().CurrentNode.Key)).Title;
```

and

```
string longtitle = new PageManager().GetPageNode(new Guid(SiteMapBase.GetCurrentProvider().CurrentNode.Key)).Page.HtmlTitle;
```

Hope it helps!

Jochem

Comment: Thanks I just saw this post I will try it out and see if this works.